# Theming with Sweave or other LaTeX like PDF Generators that are R friendly

Tags: pdf, r, sweave

Is there a way to generate a theme for sweave documents? I have a number of reports that I generate monthly, where I use R to generate the text, tables and images. But now I'm stuck in the rut of copying and pasting this information into MS Publisher placing the text in a themed document that we had a graphic designer make for us.

What I'd like to do is replicate the design, and get rid of the need to copy paste.

Is this possible with Sweave? Or another tool?

Comment: While SWeave is basically a LaTeX template engine this is more a pure LaTeX question; try on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You will need to make a style file (.sty). Good luck with replicating the design.

Comment: @Roman Good designers are deeply devoted to OpenSource and know LaTeX perfectly :-]

Comment: @mbq, I'm not saying it's not possible. I didn't designate a time frame in which this can be done, either. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

As Roman says, you can create a `.sty` file to replicate the theme in your Latex output.

You could also tinker with the [R2wd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2wd/index.html) package to make it work with Publisher.  (This is likely nontrivial.)

The 'third way' is to use [R2HTML](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2HTML/index.html) to output your content as a web page, then import that HTML file into Publisher.

Comment: LaTex is really good for scientific documents and nice PDF output. But I think producing Html and make stylesheet to get the design right. Easier than to design your own Latex .sty.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could try [odfweave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) which allows you to create an [Libre Office](http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/) (nee Open Office) .odf document with R code, tables and graphs in a similar way to Sweave.  Their are a few difference, and in some ways because you can edit odf documents in a gui then it's easier to do for amateurs.

Libre Office/Open Office also allows you to save the resulting odf document as a word document (or many other formats).